# PHP Mail Sending BCC not wordking

Tags: php

I am using PHP mail and trying to send BCC, but for some reason since I've added the lines with //ADDED NEW on it , it's just now sending any emails at all.

Here is the full code:

```
 $to = "me@gmail.com";
 $bcc = $row['recipients']; //ADDED NEW
 $subject = $row['subject'];
 $message = $row['text_body'];

 $headers = "From: " . strip_tags('me@gmail.com') . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags('me@gmail.com') . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Bcc: $emailList\r\n"; //ADDED NEW
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 

 mail($to, $bcc, $subject, $message, $headers); // $bcc ADDED NEW
```

Why is this not sending?

Comment: The `mail()` function doesn't have a `bcc` argument. Read the [documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Where do you set `$emailList`?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk There's no PHP code in that answer, I don't see how it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem,

1. Set `$bcc` but in `$headers` does not using it
2. Putting invalid argument into `mail` function.

Try this

```
$to = "me@gmail.com";
$bccList = $row['recipients']; //ADDED NEW
$subject = $row['subject'];
$message = $row['text_body'];

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags('me@gmail.com') . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags('me@gmail.com') . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $bccList\r\n"; //ADDED NEW
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // $bcc ADDED NEW
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `$bcc` argument to the `mail()` function. It should be:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The blind recipients will be retrieved from the `Bcc` header in `$headers`.